# Call getexpress checkout in paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am using [this](http://www.phpmoot.com/php-paypal-recurring-with-express-checkout-payment-gateway/) link to create `Recurring Payment`.

I am able to call `set express checkout` but I am not able to call `get express checkout` using `token` that is generated in `set express checkout`

Can anybody help me?

Comment: what error you are getting ? `print_r` your response

Comment: no error but how can i pass token that is to be generated in set express checkout

Comment: as per the link provided by you, token is fetched using  `$token = urlencode(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['token']));
`